# type conversion (character to numeric back to character)

Tags: r

For manipulating ID's that are given as character I tried the following:

```
> a <- "603144790381830143"
> as.numeric(a)
[1] 6.031448e+17
> as.character(as.numeric(a))
[1] "603144790381830144"
```

I use:

```
R version 3.1.3 (2015-03-09) -- "Smooth Sidewalk"
Copyright (C) 2015 The R Foundation for Statistical Computing
Platform: x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu (64-bit)
```

Now needless to say this is unexpected behaviour (for me).
Is there something I should be aware of in handling doubles?

Comment: OK, but then I would expect another outcome for the following
`> a <- "603144790381830143"`
`> options(digits = 22) ; as.numeric(a)`
`[1] 603144790381830144`

Comment: It seems like a floating points rounding issue. Every double that has more than 17 digits will be represented differently after the 17th digit. See for example `70000000000000000000000`. It probably related to `.Machine$double.eps`. Either way, take a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9508518/why-are-these-numbers-not-equal)

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it using the bit64 package:

```
library(bit64)
> as.character(as.integer64(a))
[1] "603144790381830143"
```